# Obj-C - NSPredicate - Can I implement an 'or IF' statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm trying to write a filter with NSPredicate that states:

> IF field_Uid contains **47** and field_Target contains **202**...display these items

This portion works great. However, I also want to show items in which the reverse is true, eg.:

> **OR IF** fieldUid contains **202** and fieldTarget contains **47**...display these
>   items also

Right now, I have the  following code:

```
NSString *targetedUser = @"47";

NSString *myID = @"202";       

NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fieldUid contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fieldTarget contains[cd] %@", myID];  

//E.G. See p3 & p4 being the reverse?

//   NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fieldUid contains[cd] %@", myID];
//    NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fieldTarget contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

NSCompoundPredicate *p = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2/*, p3, p4*/]];

NSArray *filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

How would I write in the latter? I'm not sure how to do it without making the statement requiring all 4 lines to be true? (See commented out code - I've left it in so you can see what I mean...)

Comment: You can use AND and OR operations within a predicate statement, as in `"(fieldUid contains[cd] %@ AND fieldTarget contains[cd] %@) OR (fieldUid contains[cd] %@ AND fieldTarget contains[cd] %@)"` ... add on the parameters, of course.

Comment: `NSCompoundPredicate *pIntermediary1 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2,]];NSCompoundPredicate * pIntermediary2 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p3, p4,]]; NSCompoundPredicate *pFinal = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pIntermediary1, pIntermediary2]];               NSArray *filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];`?

Comment: @Larme Please don't post an answer as a comment. Especially one full of code.

Comment: @DonMag Tried this but my syntax appears to be incorrect? I get error "unable to parse..."? Can you post code in answer format?

Answer (score 0):

Just combine two compound "and" predicates using a compound "or" predicate.

You have the first compound "and" predicate in your question. Create the 2nd compound "and" predicate as needed.

Now use `[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:]` passing in the two "and" compound predicates.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
NSString *targetedUser = @"47";
NSString *myID = @"202";  

//this will easily fix your issue, simply update your query like this

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(fieldUid contains[cd] %@ AND fieldTarget contains[cd] %@) OR (fieldUid contains[cd] %@ AND fieldTarget contains[cd] %@)", targetedUser, myID, myID, targetedUser];
NSArray *filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Comment: @DonMag yes updated the answer, thanks for notifying.. :)